# How to decrypt a STE file, config file forprograms (Security)

Tags: security, encryption, config, dreamweaver

ste file. This is a configuration file that will which is used by a program as a security. It contains the mac address of a computer. I've been racking my brain endleslly in order to try and decrypt it. Does anyone have any ideas.?

Heres the link to the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10l2QVjnHYMDjP1e0FuLC8gUvAWtEXvyU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am so sorry, I think the paragraph got jumbled up as I was writing.